# React-Native:Firebase Google Sign-in is not working in react-native android app release version

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-authentication

I have a react-native app which is integrated with Firebase. I have enabled Google Sign in authentication. Google-Sign in works in debug mode but does not work in release mode. I have added all the SHA1 keys in my Firebase project.

I tried adding release keys in the debug signingConfigs in app->build.gradle and sign-in works perfectly fine.

But when I install the release apk in the emulator using below command, the app crashes when clicked on sign-in button.

react-native run-android --no-jetifier --variant=release

Note:I have added all the SHA1 keys (debug, release & SHA1 from App signing key certificate in google playstore) in Firebase Project.

Comment: Could you try using a real device and then check.

Comment: Hi, I have the same error, I have also added the release sha1 and sha256, and it's still not working. can you tell me how you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

### **Solution when you don't signup APK yet and use no SSH URLs**

This answer useful only when you are in develop yer and you need run current app on release mode to test `run-android --variant=release`

The problem is when you use an api urls with `http` and not `https` just after to auth user with google service, the request is block google and interrupt process. Which prevents that google sign in finish success.

**SOLUTION:**

- Go to: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- find: `<application ...`
- put: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Final AndroidManifest.xml/application should look like this:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If you need solved this error when you have SSH urls or Google Play Sign In you need use:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357408/6673414