# React Native Google Sign In Not Working In Release Mode

Tags: react-native

I'm building release apk with `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` but it doesn't work. BUT, it works on my real device which is connected during `react-native run-android --variant=release`. I also added both debug and release SHA1 to Firebase.

Answer (score 16):

**Google Login does NOT work when downloading my app from the play store.**

Check if "Google Play App Signing" is enabled for your app. If it is enabled, you will need to add the "App signing certificate" SHA-1 to your firebase console.

You can find it at: App -> Release (in left sidebar) -> Setup -> App integrity. Under the App signing key certificate, copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint into firebase console for the Android app.

If you are not using firebase, and your app is enabled for "Google Play App Signing": Go to "https://console.developers.google.com/" -> click "Credential" in the right panel -> Find "Client ID" for type "Android" under "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" section -> Edit -> replace "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" with the one from App -> Release (in left sidebar) -> Setup -> App integrity -> App signing key certificate.

[Google Login does NOT work when downloading my app from the play store](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/HEAD/docs/android-guide.md#google-login-does-not-work-when-using-internal-app-sharing)

Comment: Thanks for replying! But the real problem is with my server implementation that it doesn't have SSL cert (http). Solved by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `application` tag in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Adding SHA key to firebase console solved my issue

Comment: your link saved me. i added both SHA-1's.   Google Play Console go to Development Tools-> Internal App Sharing->App Certificate and there is another SHA-1 fingerprint to add to firebase.

Comment: Thank you! I was generating my SHA-1 with the keytool but I needed to copy the SHA-1 from the Play Console signing. Works now!